# Package passes pre-release tests, but fails source debian build

Tags: ubuntu, pre-release, ros-electric, ubuntu-oneiric, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to release the clearpath_husky package on electric. The pre-release builds pass (see [here](http://build.willowgarage.com//job/prerelease_electric_clearpath_husky_oneiric_amd64/1/) and [here](http://build.willowgarage.com//job/prerelease_electric_clearpath_husky_oneiric_i386/1/), but the source debian build fails on oneiric. I receive the following email:

```
Stack [clearpath_husky-0.2.1] in distro [electric] succeeded on the following OS platforms:
['lucid', 'maverick', 'natty']

================================================================================
ERRORS
================================================================================
Stack [clearpath_husky-0.2.1] in distro [electric] failed to build on the following OS platforms:
['oneiric']

[oneiric]: stack [clearpath_husky] does not have valid debian package dependencies for release [oneiric]
================================================================================
```

Using `rosmake` and `rosdep` on an oneiric machine seems to resolve all dependencies correctly and build this package without issue. I'm not sure where to go from here in terms of troubleshooting. Can I simulate the ROS build pipeline locally to see what the source of the error is?

**Edit**:
To clarify, everything works fine on my machine the error only occurs when the release has been submitted to the ROS servers. The `create.py` script also runs just fine and produces no error output.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29157/package-passes-pre-release-tests,-but-fails-source-debian-build/) by [abencz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1851/abencz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- 99% of the time the error means there are issues resolving rosdep keys for the Oneiric platform.
- Most of the time you can diagnose this issue by simply looking at the console output when you run the create.py script.
- Most of the time this is caused by not having an up-to-date ros-electric release on your system (i.e. something that your stack depends on)

On ROS Electric (*only*), you can run the following code snippet:

```
from ros import rosdeb
rosdeb.rosutil.stack_rosdeps('my_stack_name', '/path/to/my_stack_name', 'oneiric')
```

This snippet will not work on ROS Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1